# How can I perform voice recognition for single words, without an Internet connection, on iOS?

Tags: ios, voice-recognition

How can I perform voice recognition for single words, without an Internet connection, on iOS?

Comment: OpenEars is gonna be your best bet.

Answer (score -2):

Just to clarify Richards reply:
It is limited and may not be what you wanted, though most parts of voice or speech recognition is done on the server side which is true for SIRI the Apple system.
Although there are other projects and libraries, like [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/).
There might be others as well, feel free to search for them.

Unfortunately I do not have any experience with this library.